# How to insert large amount of data into a ClickHouse DB?

Tags: clickhouse

I have an instance of a ClickHouse server running and I have successfully connected to it through a client. I'm using Tabix.io to run my queries. I have created a DB and a table called "names". I want to input a lot of randomly generated names inside that table. I know that running multiple commands like this:

```
insert into names (id, first_name, last_name) values (1, 'Stephana', 'Bromell');
insert into names (id, first_name, last_name) values (2, 'Babita', 'Leroux');
insert into names (id, first_name, last_name) values (3, 'Pace', 'Christofides');
...
insert into names (id, first_name, last_name) values (999, 'Ralph', 'Jackson');
```

is not supported and therefore it is only the first query that is executed. In other words only *Stephana Bromell* appear in the "names" table.

**What is the ClickHouse alternative for inserting larger amounts of data?**

Comment: consider using [Buffer Table Engine](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/buffer/). See related answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52437466/303298

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple small inserts in clickhouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40592010/multiple-small-inserts-in-clickhouse)

Comment: @vladimir Thanks! I will definately use buffer tables at a later phase.

Answer (score 5):

multiple values in a single insert.

insert into names (id, first_name, last_name) values (1, 'Stephana', 'Bromell') (2, 'Babita', 'Leroux') (3, 'Pace', 'Christofides') (999, 'Ralph', 'Jackson');

Answer (score 4):

How about batch inserting using [http client](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/http/) with [CSV](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#csv)

1. create csv file (names.csv) with content:

```
1,Stephana,Bromell
2,Babita,Leroux
3,Pace,Christofides
...
999,Ralph,Jackson
```

2. call HTTP API:

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -T "./names.csv" \
 'http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20names%20FORMAT%20CSV'
```

Comment: Awesome Thanks. I'll try this too.